# Typescript, How to get the value of an object based on its key?

Tags: typescript

How do I implement KeysToValues so that I can return the corresponding value based on the second parameter?

```
type KeysToValues<T, K> = any

type A = KeysToValues<{a: number, b: string}, ['a', 'b']>
// [number, string]
```

One more last in my realization... .any[]

```
type KeysToValues<O extends Record<string, any>, K> = K extends [
  infer G,
  ...infer L
]
  ? G extends keyof O
    ? L extends (keyof O)[]
      ? [O[G], ...KeysToValues<O, L>]
      : O[G]
    : any
  : any

type A = KeysToValues<{ a: string }, ['a']>
// [string, ...any[]]
```

Comment: Don't overthink too much. These can be done with one-liners. You don't need to use an array. You could use just a union: `type KeysToValues<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T> = T[K]` and then `KeysToValues<{a:string, b:number}, "a" | "b">`. Still, using an array is the same I've done but wrapping the needed parts with `Array<XXX>`, for example `type KeysToValues<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T> = Array<T[K]>` will make the KeysToValues output to be an array instead.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBQY4w) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I think OP requests for a tuple with the types in exact order, what you propose doesn't meet that

Comment: @wonderflame ohhhh I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, but it shows `any` in the list because you are returning `any` at some point. Just change your `any` to `[]` so an empty array is concatenated to the result:

```js
type KeysToValues<O extends Record<string, any>, K> = K extends [
  infer G,
  ...infer L
]
  ? G extends keyof O
    ? L extends (keyof O)[]
      ? [O[G], ...KeysToValues<O, L>]
      : O[G]
    : []
  : []

type A = KeysToValues<{ a: string, b: number, c: boolean }, ['a', 'c']>
// [string, boolean]
```